# Validating and conversion of float

Tags: c++, string, validation, floating-point

I am writing a program where I have to verify that the inputted value by the user is a valid float number. So, I've tried this method:

```
string test;
cin >> test;
float n;
n = atof(test.c_str());
cout << n << endl;
```

But it doesn't seem to do the job; when it does the conversion, the numbers after the `.` are lost. How can I validate that a valid floating point number is used in C++ (not 11)?

Examples:

```
INPUT: 32.e
OUTPUT: 32 (should be error)

INPUT: 2a.1234
OUTPUT: 2 (should be error)
```

Comment: Read the data (line) into a string. Use the `strtod()` function (from `<cstdlib>` or a more C++-like alternative) to do the conversion. Given the address of a suitable pointer to char, `strtod()` also reports where it stops converting.  You can decide whether you want to object to what appears after that (are spaces, tabs, newlines allowed, for example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use formatted reads combined with a check if everything is read you can determine if the [complete] value is a valid floating point number, e.g.:

```
int main()
{
    for (std::string test; std::cin >> test; ) {
        std::istringstream in(test);
        double value;
        if (in >> value >> std::ws && in.eof()) {
            std::cout << "the string '" << test << "' is a valid floating point number\n";
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "the string '" << test << "' is not a valid floating point number\n";
        }
    }
}
```

The test does ignore whitespace surrounding the string. If that isn't desirable, the manipulator `std::noskipws` can be used and the use of `std::ws` can be omitted. Alternatively you can use `strtod()` do determine if the entire value represents a floating point number.

What `atof()` is to simply see if the initial string of its argument is valid floating point number which is the case for the examples you quoted.

Comment: Good solution, it seems to work on all cases I could've thought. I need for a float thought, which does the job perfectly, so strtod() isn't an option, unless I make a lot of conversions.

Comment: Just a few questions, to make sure I understand your example correctly, as I'm a beginner. Firstly, we use a for loop (can be a while or other type as well to keep the input going), then we declare a stringstream called in with the value of the string. Then we try to write the value of the string to the value of the variable of type double and the std::ws ignores any white spaces in the string, and in.eof() goes until the end of the string (to write all elements) and if it's true (didn't fail until the end) it returns true, else it's a false?

Comment: @user2943407: `for` and `while` are just slightly different loop constructors: you can use either for the purpose. `in` is an `std::istringstream` from which the value is tried to be _read_ (not _written_; writing would be `out << x`). The floating point number in read using formatted input. The formatted read will skip leading whitespace, read the value and stop on the first non-matching character. The `std::ws` is used to skip trailing whitespace (if any; as the strings were just read there won't be any). Finally, it is checked if all input was consumed using `in.eof()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main() {
    float f;
    cin >> f;
    if (!cin.fail()) {
        cout << f << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Invalid input" << endl;
    }
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

The `fail()` function checks the `failbit` and `badbit` on the stream. `failbit` signals what you want, if there was a logical error on I/O operation (example: try to read a float, but couldn't parse the token to a float) and `badbit` signals if there was a read/writing error on i/o operation (could not read/write token at all).

Comment: That will accept the two string which were considered to be invalid as valid, too!

Comment: @DietmarKühl give example

Comment: @bolov For some reason, when I enter an invalid value, it keeps displaying the error until I close the program.

Comment: @bolov: e.g., `2k` is considered to be a valid floating point number but it isn't. The `2` is parsed as number but the example quoted in the question clearly ask for `2k` to be considered invalid. You can also use the two strings from the original question which "should be error".

Comment: @DietmarKühl Then he needs to check that he read all input, like in your answer

Comment: @bolov I'm just using the code you provided. A simple program to check if a float is valid or invalid. No other code involved.

Comment: This can be improved, but I am too tired now. I will edit this tomorrow.

Comment: The OP used atof which has the same limitation.  As long as the front part of the string is a valid float, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer really depends on whether you want an entire line of input validated.  atof will work even if only the beginning of the input is a float (e.g. 3.3a, 4.72abc).  If you want all of the input stream validated, then you'll have to use getline to read the string and parse it.  Simply check for the existence of only digits plus a single '.'.

I credit the C++ faq lite for the basic idea.
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/istream-and-ignore.html

My example is in a loop so that you can more easily see what I mean.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
      double value = 0;

      while ((std::cout << "Enter a floating point number\n ")
             && !(std::cin >> value)) {
        std::cout << "\nThat's not a floating point number\n ";
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
      }

      std::cout << "You entered " << value << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's quite good, but it fails if you type for example 2...55 or 2.5.5

Comment: Remember that -3.21e+46 is a valid `double` constant on most systems.  That is, you need to allow for signs, and maybe for exponents too.  And that's before you get to consider hexadecimal constants too.

Comment: Good point.  I overlooked the complexity of a float so manual parsing is a bad idea. It looks like the  one marked as answer is better.  The key thing is getting the data into the program as a string first because the eof can tell whether the string stream has any additional characters.